# Counting the Occurrences of a User Specified Character in a String

Tags: java, string, for-loop, character

My program is supposed to count the number of occurrences a user inputted character appears in a string. For some reason, my program does not execute the for loop. Right after it prints out "Enter the string to search: ", it doesn't let me input a string and prints out: "There are 0 occurrences of '(inputted character)' in '(inputted string)'." on a new line. I need it to be able to find the occurrences of the character over any given amount of words inputted as the string. What can I do to make it function properly? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountCharacters {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a character for which to search: ");
        char ch = input.next().charAt(0);

        System.out.println("Enter the string to search: ");
        String str = input.nextLine();

        int counter = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (ch == str.charAt(i)) {
                counter++;

            }

        }
        System.out.printf("There are %d occurrences of '%s' in '%s'.", counter, ch, str);
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: Also as a side note, if you had a List of Characters, you could use  Collections.frequency(); one line to do your job :)

Comment: @devnull: thanks, that should help.

Comment: @WhoAmI: I'll have to try that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that the `next()` method doesn't consume the new-line character that is entered when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Since that character is still there waiting to be read, the `nextLine()` consumes it. To fix this you can add a `nextLine()` after the `next()` call:

```
char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
input.nextLine(); // consumes new-line character

// ...
```

For futher information, you could read this [post](http://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/).

Answer (score 2):

After entering your number I guess you are pressing `<enter>` so this needs to be chewed up before entering your string

try

```
char ch = input.next().charAt(0);
input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the string to search: ");
String str = input.nextLine();
```